# pandas drop_duplicates condition on two other columns values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a datframe with columns A,B and C.

Column A is where there are duplicates. Column B is where there is email value or NaN. Column C is where there is 'wait' value or a number.

My dataframe has duplicate values in A. I would like to keep those who have a non-NaN value in B and the non 'wait' value in C (ie numbers).

How could I do that on a df dataframe?

I have tried df.drop_duplicates('A') but i dont see any conditions on other columns

Edit :
sample data :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'B':['a@b.com',np.nan,np.nan,'c@d.com','np.nan',np.nan],'C':[123,456,567,'wait','wait','wait']})
>>> df
   A        B     C
0  1  a@b.com   123
1  1      NaN   456
2  2      NaN   567
3  2  c@d.com  wait
4  3   np.nan  wait
5  3      NaN  wait
```

I would like a resulting dataframe as

```
>>> df
   A        B     C
0  1  a@b.com   123
1  2  c@d.com   567
2  3   np.nan  wait
```

Thank you
Best,

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question and expected ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution sorting per `A, C` columns with test if match `wait` first and then get first non missing value if exist per groups by column `A`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['A', 'C'], key = lambda x: x.eq('wait')).groupby('A').first()
print (df)
         B     C
A               
1  a@b.com   123
2  c@d.com   567
3   np.nan  wait
```